# Need to count certain rows based on date criteria in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and have a table with these 2 columns.  I need to count an ORG_ID once ONLY IF the EndDate for every row or that ORG_ID falls within/before the timeframe of '1-1-2018' and '1-31-2018' (or before but NOT after) for ALL rows for that org.  An ORE with an EndDate of NULL would also NOT be in my results

```
ORG_ID              EndDate    
99968042            1/31/2018    
99968042            2/14/2018    
99968042            2/14/2018    
99900699            1/10/2018    
99900699            1/10/2018    
99900699            1/10/2018    
99900699            1/10/2018    
99899776            1/20/2018    
99843366           12/17/2017    
99843366             1/4/2018    
99841000             2/1/2016    
99651255             NULL
99651255             1/15/2018
```

The rows that should output are:

```
99900699    
99899776    
99843366
```

I haven't tried anything, because I can't think how to approach it.

So now I've tried this:

```
select distinct ORG_ID
from ##PLCMT p1
where not exists (
    select *
    from ##PLCMT p2
    where p1.ORG_ID = p2.ORG_ID and
          (p1.EndDate <= '2018-01-01' or p1.enddate >= '2018-01-31' or p1.EndDate is NULL)
   )
```

and it is still resulting back an org that has a NULL enddate, I can't figure out why.  ORG_ID 3098376 is in my results but if I look at all the rows for that ORG_ID, it looks like this:

```
select *
from ##PLCMT
where org_id = '3098376'
```

results:
    ORG_ID     EndDate
    3098376    2017-09-11
    3098376    NULL
    3098376    NULL

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, where did the Oracle tag come from?  I'm just curious.

Comment: In this line:  `and (p1.EndDate <= '2018-01-01' or p1.enddate >= '2018-01-31' or p1.EndDate` you should replace every `p1` with `p2`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `group by` and `having` and `NOT IN` (to eliminate those who have any NULL value):

```
SELECT org_id
FROM t
GROUP BY org_id
WHERE org_id NOT IN (SELECT org_id FROM t WHERE enddate IS NULL)
HAVING MAX(enddate) <= '2018-01-31';
```

Your are probably safe with this logic:

```
having max(enddate) < '2018-02-01'
```

This works even if `enddate` has a time component.

Comment: Yes, I think that will work. I've never used "having" much so I don't think of it.  And I just added                                                                                                                               where enddate is not NULL

Comment: Actually, this isn't working for the NULL enddate.  I am getting ORG_ID 99651255              no matter what I try

Answer (score 1):

Another way is with NOT EXISTS()

```
SELECT DISTINCT org_id
from t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM t t1
  WHERE t1.org_id=t.org_id
  AND (t1.enddate > '20180131' OR t1.enddate IS NULL)
)
```

Comment: I thought it worked with where p1.ORG = p2.ORG
and (p1.EndDate <= '2018-01-01' or p1.enddate >= '2018-01-31' or p1.EndDate is NULL)
)  but I am still finding an org that has a NULL and an enddate in January in my results :(

Comment: Because you should be filtering the `p2` enddates instead of the `p1` enddates.